# What is the square symbol on the Wii U gamepad?

Tags: wii-u

There is this square symbol right below the d-pad on the Wii U gamepad:

[image: Wii U gamepad picture]

What does it mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the location of the NFC reader/writer built into the gamepad ([see page 8](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/downloads/wiiu_operations_manual_en.pdf)):

> NFC (near-field communication) location
>
> Built-in NFC feature allows the system to read or write to an enabled card or other device.
>
> This works with Wii U software exclusively designed to use this feature
>   (see game packaging for compatibility information)

To the best of my knowledge, [Pokémon Rumble U](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Rumble_U) is currently the only game with any support for that feature.

Comment: Sometimes is good to RTFM eh? Thank you (:

Comment: BTW there are a lot of games that support NFC. Search for Amiibo for a half dozen examples, but the newest Smash Bros (both WiiU & 3DS) is a prime example. Might be worth updating your answer.